# backup svn script on linux does not work?

Tags: linux, backup, bash, script, svn

I have a script that runs on Linux Ubuntu Server every dat at 5am.
This script backups all my SVN in this way:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 svnadmin dump /home/xxx/svn/p1 > /home/xxx/svn-backup/p1
 svnadmin dump /home/xxx/svn/p2 > /home/xxx/svn-backup/p2
 svnadmin dump /home/xxx/svn/p3 > /home/xxx/svn-backup/p3
```

The problem is that only the first project (p1) is really dumped.
The rest of the projects are files with this text in them:

SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2

UUID: 895acea3-fcd0-46fa-908a-4b43fc3278af

Revision-number: 0
Prop-content-length: 56
Content-length: 56

K 8
svn:date
V 27
2009-11-12T15:25:00.461875Z
PROPS-END

(edit)
When running the script from command line it backups all the repositories and does this problem only when running from cron.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for that.
The problem was something related to the output buffering of the cron job and the cron stop the script when it reaches some limit.
What i have done in order to solve the problem is two things:

1. in the cron i redirected the output into /dev/null

   ```
   0 5 * * * /home/xxx/svn-backup/run-backup > /dev/null
   ```
2. In the run-backup script i redirected the output into /dev/null too

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   svnadmin dump /home/xxx/svn/p1 > /home/xxx/svn-backup/p1 2>/dev/null
   svnadmin dump /home/xxx/svn/p2 > /home/xxx/svn-backup/p2 2>/dev/null
   svnadmin dump /home/xxx/svn/p3 > /home/xxx/svn-backup/p3 2>/dev/null
   ```

That made my script working !

Update: This is actually also explained on stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323933/crontab-doesnt-finish-svndump

It seems cron terminates the execution once certain limit is reached in the stderr output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a silly question, but do repositories `p2` and `p3` have any committed content/revisions yet? It's obvious they are repositories, otherwise you would have error messages instead of the output you have. However, when I created an empty repository and ran `svnadmin dump` on it, I got exactly the behavior you describe. Try checking out a copy of the repositories and running `svn log` to see if there are any committed revisions. Again, maybe this is a silly question, but it's easy to check.

Comment: @Daniel. Thanks for the idea. But i forgot to mention (edited) that when i run the script from command line manually and not from the cron it dumps all the repositories. The problem occurs only when running in cron.